# jsf 2 with jquery-lang-js plugin not translating h:outputLabel in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jquery-plugins, jsf-2

I'm using [this](https://github.com/coolbloke1324/jquery-lang-js) plugin inorder to translate my page. everything is working great in IE8 but in IE9 the tags of `h:outputLabel` are not being translated.. why is that , and how can I fix this?

Example of my code:

```
<h:body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$().ready(function () {
window.lang = new jquery_lang_js();

window.lang.run();
window.lang.change(language);

$('*').each(function()
{              
    var attr = $(this).attr('lang');
    if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) 
    {
        $(this).attr("lang", language);                              
    }
}); 
}); 
 </script>
<h:form id="testForm" dir="#{bean.dir}" >  
<h:panelGrid id="testTable" columns="2" dir="#{bean.dir}" rowClasses="rowTop,rowBottom"          columnClasses="column1,column2">
<h:outputLabel value="User Code:" for="userCode"  lang="en"/>
<h:outputLabel/>                           
<h:inputText id="userCode" value="#{bean.userCode}"/>             
     <h:message id="userCodeMSG" for="userCode" showDetail="false" showSummary="true" styleClass="message"/>                                                 
 </h:panelGrid>  
 </h:form>

</h:body>
```

Please help!!
Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I can help you but I have some ideas :

1. You can maybe put this metatag

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
   ```

   inside of  to force IE9 to render page like IE8
2. Or you can wait that all the document is loaded and after that launch your function. You can do that with

   ```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
       //Put your code here
   });
   ```